# read xml element by excluding its attribute using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform the given xml input using XSLT and I want to exclude the "xmlns" attribute of root element from the transformed output

my input xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<library xmlns="https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.2/CWLEntityExport.xsd">
 <book>
  <title>Programming in C</title>
  <author>Balagurusamy</author>
  <country>India</country>
  <price>165</price>
  <year>1998</year>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>Professional ASP.NET 4 in C# and VB</title>
  <author>Bill Evjen, Scott Hanselman, Devin Rader</author>
  <country>USA</country>
  <price>580</price>
  <year>2010</year>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Programming</title>
  <author>Robert Vieira</author>
  <country>USA</country>
  <price>520</price>
  <year>2009</year>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>Professional LINQ</title>
  <author>Scott Klein</author>
  <country>USA</country>
  <price>425</price>
  <year>2008</year>
 </book>
</library>
```

and expected xml output after transformation using XSLT is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookList>
<Book>
<title>Programming in C</title>
<author>Balagurusamy</author>
<country>India</country>
</Book>
<Book>
<title>Professional ASP.NET 4 in C# and VB</title>
<author>Bill Evjen, Scott Hanselman, Devin Rader</author>
<country>USA</country>
</Book>

<Book>
<title>Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Programming</title>
<author>Robert Vieira</author>
<country>USA</country>
</Book>
<Book>
<title>Professional LINQ</title>
<author>Scott Klein</author>
<country>USA</country>
</Book>

</BookList>
```

my xslt is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <BookList>
      <xsl:for-each select="library/book">
        <Book>

          <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
          </title>
          <author>
            <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
          </author>
          <country>
            <xsl:value-of select="country" />
          </country>

        </Book>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </BookList>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

what changes do i need to make in above XSLT to get the given expected output xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to transform the given xml input using XSLT and I want to
>   exclude the "xmlns" attribute of root element from the transformed
>   output
>
> my input xml is
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
>
> <library xmlns="https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.2/CWLEntityExport.xsd">
>  <book>
>   <title>Programming in C</title>
>  .  .  .
> ```

**A very short, simple and generic way of doing this is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note that no namespace needs to be declared in the transformation and no specific XPath expression is needed!

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (or, in general, on any document whose default namespace needs to be eliminated), the wanted, correct result is produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library>
   <book>
      <title>Programming in C</title>
      <author>Balagurusamy</author>
      <country>India</country>
      <price>165</price>
      <year>1998</year>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Professional ASP.NET 4 in C# and VB</title>
      <author>Bill Evjen, Scott Hanselman, Devin Rader</author>
      <country>USA</country>
      <price>580</price>
      <year>2010</year>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Programming</title>
      <author>Robert Vieira</author>
      <country>USA</country>
      <price>520</price>
      <year>2009</year>
   </book>
   <book>
      <title>Professional LINQ</title>
      <author>Scott Klein</author>
      <country>USA</country>
      <price>425</price>
      <year>2008</year>
   </book>
</library>
```

**Update:**

If in addition some renamings of elements are necessary, the transformation becomes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[name()='library']">
    <BookList>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </BookList>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[name()='book']">
    <Book>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Book>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[name()='price' or name()='year']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and when applied to the provided XML document, the wanted result is produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BookList>
   <Book>
      <title>Programming in C</title>
      <author>Balagurusamy</author>
      <country>India</country>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <title>Professional ASP.NET 4 in C# and VB</title>
      <author>Bill Evjen, Scott Hanselman, Devin Rader</author>
      <country>USA</country>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <title>Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Programming</title>
      <author>Robert Vieira</author>
      <country>USA</country>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <title>Professional LINQ</title>
      <author>Scott Klein</author>
      <country>USA</country>
   </Book>
</BookList>
```

Comment: That is not the wanted result.

Comment: thanks @Dimitre  your solution works perfectly .. but in addition I don't want to select all the elements from input to the transformed xml .As you can see I want to exclude price and year from the input xml in final output.
this might be a silly question :( but I have never worked on XSLT.

Comment: @DhirajKhodade, Just add this template: `<xsl:template match="*[name() = 'price' or name()='year']" />

Comment: @DhirajKhodade, I updated the answer so that it produces the wanted renamed elements and excludes year and price

Comment: @Dimitre Thats awesome :) Thanks a lot...!

Comment: It is best to avoid patterns like `*[name()='xyz']`.  If you know the namespaces of the nodes to be selected or matched, use them. There is no advantage to be gained by trying to take a shortcut around them. On the contrary: processing is likely to be slower and, in worst case scenario, the pattern will match nodes you don't want to be matched.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Yes using specific namespaces can be slightly more efficient, depending on the case. But programmer's time is more expensive than machine time nowadays. Therefore, having a generic solution pays better in general.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to exclude the "xmlns" attribute of root element from the
>   transformed output

It's not an attribute - it's a namespace declaration. It places all elements in your input XML in a namespace bound to the declared URI.

You need to declare this namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix when addressing elements in the input XML. Without this, your XPath expressions will not select anything.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns1="https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.2/CWLEntityExport.xsd"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns1:library">
    <BookList>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns1:book">
            <Book>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:title"/>
                </title>
                <author>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:author"/>
                </author>
                <country>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:country" />
                </country>
            </Book>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </BookList>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks michael ur XSLT gives expected output.
can we make it more generic . bcoz I dont know what will be the namespace in input xml file . and as per ur answer we need to specify the same xmlns in xslt.
So is there any way that including the same xmlns in xslt wont be required.??

Comment: @DhirajKhodade How is it possible that you know the structure of your input XML, but not the namespace it's using? This is not something that's supposed to change.